# eigenvalues and eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\-2&1&0&0\\-3&-2&1&0\\-4&-3&-2&-2 \end{pmatrix}$. Show that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. What is the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Is it $A+$ or $A=$?

Comment: It is A.  Sorry that was a typo.  It is supposed to be A=

Comment: Just compute $\det(A - E)$ and verify that determinant is zero.

Comment: Thanks  I must have computed it wriong because i didnt get it.  I will try again.  But good to know I was doing the right thing.  Mahalo!!

Comment: @NNN What did you try yourself? Answers to both of your items/questions can be read off directly from the matrix because it has triangular form!

Comment: This is an upper triangle matrix!

Comment: I just got the answer! At first when I did it I got -1 ad 2 and then when I did it again just now I got -2 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

$ A - I= \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\-2&0&0&0\\-3&-2&0&0\\-4&-3&-2&-3 \end{pmatrix} \implies \mathrm{det}(A-I)=0$.

So, indeed $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Dimension of the eigenspace = Nullity of $(A-I)$ = Number of dependent columns of $(A-I) = 1$.